# I have a List with Checkboxes and i want to every item on the List to add a quantity field, so the user can enter a value like 1,2,3 etc

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

[image]

so , I want my screen to look like  dis . please help me.

Comment: You could have a hidden EditText that appears when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: sorry im not getting you ..

Comment: is any one  there to help me as i m need help n new to developing .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
Button minus = (Button)....

TextView tv = (TextView)findView.... //to show the number of value

plus.onClickListener(View.onClickListener()
{
     int val = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText());
     val++;
     tv.setText(val);

});
```

You are incrementing the value of number of item as the plus/minus between being hit. And you are setting the initial value to Zero (0). I think you can do it from here... Cheers